# How to resolve error in git pull from bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, rpc, git-pull

Getting following error when making pull request on bitbucket.
The project is written in python-django framework.

```
remote: Counting objects: 3703, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3030/3030), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the problem is at the remote end. It's probably transient and probably even fixed by the time you are reading this. However if the problem perists, switch to git+ssh

[Here's how](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html)

> To use SSH with Bitbucket, you create an SSH identity containing a
>   private key (on your local computer) and a public key (uploaded to
>   Bitbucket) which create a key pair. After setting up SSH between your
>   local system and Bitbucket, your system uses the key pair to
>   authenticate you automatically to anything to which the associated
>   account has access.

You will need to change your git remote setting with

```
git remote --set-url name ssh://git@bitbucket....
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem was due to internet speed.

Comment: yes that's what I said it might be a transient error